# Where can find a precise GOOGLE ML json specification for Entity Extraction?

Tags: json, machine-learning, named-entity-extraction

I am trying to generate my training samples using JSONL specification I found somewhere on the Google ML site. But when importing my data, I get:

> ***Error: annotation 1 on line 1 of gs://tx_harris_rel_0/tx_harris_rel_0.jsonl referenced by
>   gs://tx_harris_rel_0/tx_harris_rel_0.csv: The text content is not
>   interchange valid.***

(repeated for all my annotations, for each jsonl line/document).

I do not see any obvious error, such as unbalanced parentheses or miss-typed key.
This is an example of my data (single line):

```
{ "annotations": [{ "text_extraction": { "text_segment": { "end_offset": 96, "start_offset": 84} }, "display_name": "_NAME_TO_" }, { "text_extraction": { "text_segment": { "end_offset": 184, "start_offset": 167} }, "display_name": "_NAME_FROM_" }], "text_snippet": {"content": "RELEASE OF CHILD SUPPORT LIEN\n\nTo the County Clerk: Harris County, Texas\nObligor:\tPETE VASQUEZ\n\nDate of Birth: 11/21/1971\n\nDL#:\txxxxx413\nSSN:\txxx-xx-x629\nObligee:\tCHRISTINA L PYRON\n\nCourt:\t311 TH JUDICIAL DISTRICT, HARRIS COUNTY, TEXAS\nCause #:\t9443004\n\nAG#:\t0213575481\tUNIT:0615E\n\nChild support lien being released: U396484 filed on May 18,2000.\n\nIn accordance with Texas Family Code § 157.321, the Office of the Attorney General of the State of Texas releases the child support lien described above.\n\nUnder penalty of perjury, I affirm and declare the foregoing to be a true statement.\n\nMaribdl Davila\nOffice of the Attorney General\nChild Support Division\n\nState of Texas\n\nCounty of Travis\n\nBefore me, the undersigned notary public, on this day personally appeared Maribel Davila known to me to be the person whose name is subscribed to the foregoing instrument and acknowledged to me that he/she executed the same for the purposes and consideration therein expressed.\n\nGiven under my hand and seal of office on December 28,2016.\n\nNotary Public\n\nLAURA DICKERSON\nNotary Public.State of Texas\n\nRELEASE OF LIEN\nPage I of 1\nNotary ID #12890916 3\nCommission ExpA'ARCH 09,2020\nNotary without Bond '\n\f"} }
```

Comment: Please add what tools / programming language you are using to generate the training samples.

Comment: Well, I solved my problem, painfully using 'binary search' method between a small, typed-in file and (gradually reduced) generated one. The problem was \v (vertical tab character) and perhaps some other control characters (< /u020). There is nothing mentioned in documentation, but GOOGLE ML does not like vertical tab in ML text content.Unfortunately, my OCR Engine tends to generate them (and other surprises) here and there.

Comment: For completeness, the generating code is Java, writing UTF-8 print stream, with explicit escapes as required by JSON. The \v, control characters and many other 'special effects' such as about 8 flavors of dash character (i.e. EM_DASH) are coming from ABBYY Ocr Engine.

Comment: I suggest you to put your previous comment as an answer for other to reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was \v (vertical tab character) and perhaps some other control characters (< /u020). There is nothing mentioned in documentation, but GOOGLE ML does not like vertical tab in ML text content. Unfortunately, my OCR Engine tends to generate them (and other surprises) here and there.
Documentation under https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare?_ga=2.263860879.-2053288092.1582141786
helps (expand the Entity Extraction), but I do not see too much about text content.